# Update or add data on nested array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am new to mongodb. I want to update or add a new array value on existing document.

My input is:

```
 {
  "_id" : "Tx8Yo3FJC7WpqNpGs",
  "sharedId" : "LnkvSu8zdaahHjQmu",
  "data" : [{
     "ownerId" : "100",
     "taskId" : 1000,
     "taskName" : "trip"
 },{
     "ownerId" : "100",
     "taskId" : 2000,
     "taskName" : "meeting"
 }]
}
```

1. if **ownerId** or **taskId** is same just update.
2. if **ownerId** or **taskId** is different add to current array.

Expected output is:

```
{
 "_id" : "Tx8Yo3FJC7WpqNpGs",
 "sharedId" : "LnkvSu8zdaahHjQmu",
 "data" : [{
    "ownerId" : "100",
    "taskId" : 1000,
    "taskName" : "trip"
  },{
    "ownerId" : "100",
    "taskId" : 2000,
    "taskName" : "meeting"
  },{
    "ownerId" : "100",
    "taskId" : 3000,
    "taskName" : "games"
   }
 ]
}
```

I have tried this but did not get success.

```
SharedTask.update({
  sharedId: sharedToIds,
  data: {
    ownerId: userId,
    taskId: taskId
  },
}, {
  $push: {
    data: [{
      'ownerId': userId,
      'taskId': taskId,
      'taskName': taskName
    }]
  }
}, {
  upsert: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of `$addToSet`

The `$addToSet` operator adds a value to an array unless the value is already present, in which case `$addToSet` does nothing to that array.

```
SharedTask.update({
  sharedId: sharedToIds,
}, {
  $addToSet: {
    data: {
      'ownerId': userId,
      'taskId': taskId,
      'taskName': taskName
    }
  },{
       upsert: true
    }
});
```

- $push changed to $addToSet
- data value was array, changed to single object

Comment: can you give any example. actually I am using $addToSet in place of $set, but its not working giving error.

Comment: Its giving this errro:
MinimongoError: Cannot apply **$addToSet** modifier to non-array.

Comment: Sorry,i forgot to update match query. compare with only sharedId

Comment: It won't work in case of updating taskName updation for existing one

Answer (score 0):

You can not update all the documents at a time because you are maintaining the array of object as set by updating and adding. you can do this one by one as follows.

```
var _ = require('underscore');
var updated = {
ownerId : "100",
taskId : 2000,
taskName : "meeting1" };

SharedTask.findOne({
  sharedId: sharedToIds,
}, function(err, sharedTask){
    if(!err){
       var index = _.findIndex(sharedTask.data, { taskId: updated.taskId, ownerId:updated.ownerId });
    if(~index){
        sharedTask.data[index] =  updated;
     }else{
       sharedTask.data.push(updated);
       }
      sharedTask.save(function(err){
         if(!err){ console.log("Its okay"); }
      });
    }
});
```

You can do this as above [Hiren S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1531980/hiren-s). but there is one problem in that, it will not update the existing one.